# Upvote Gem Not Working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems

I was following a tutorial on YouTube (https://github.com/mackenziechild/raddit for source code) and I am having issues getting the acts_as_votable gem to work. I checked my syntax against the repo's and it looks like everything is the same.

The error message I am getting is "undefined local variable or method `acts_as_votable'" which references these links:

app/models/link.rb:2:in `<class:Link>'
app/models/link.rb:1:in`'
app/controllers/links_controller.rb:9:in `index'

Here is the link model:

```
class Link < ActiveRecord::Base
    acts_as_votable
    belongs_to :user
    has_many :comments
end
```

And here is the controller:

```
class LinksController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_link, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]
  before_action :authenticate_user!, except: [:index, :show]
  before_action :authorized_user, only: [:edit, :update, :destroy]

  # GET /links
  # GET /links.json
  def index
    @links = Link.all
  end

  # GET /links/1
  # GET /links/1.json
  def show
  end

  # GET /links/new
  def new
    @link = current_user.links.build
  end

  # GET /links/1/edit
  def edit
  end

  # POST /links
  # POST /links.json
  def create
    @link = current_user.links.build(link_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @link.save
        format.html { redirect_to @link, notice: 'Link was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @link }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @link.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # PATCH/PUT /links/1
  # PATCH/PUT /links/1.json
  def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @link.update(link_params)
        format.html { redirect_to @link, notice: 'Link was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @link }
      else
        format.html { render :edit }
        format.json { render json: @link.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # DELETE /links/1
  # DELETE /links/1.json
  def destroy
    @link.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to links_url, notice: 'Link was successfully destroyed.' }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end

  def upvote
    @link = Link.find(params[:id])
    @link.upvote_by current_user
    redirect_to :back
  end

  def downvote
    @link = Link.find(params[:id])
    @link.downvote_from current_user
    redirect_to :back
  end

  private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_link
      @link = Link.find(params[:id])
    end

    def authorized_user
      @link = current_user.links.find_by(id: params[:id])
      redirect_to links_path, notice: "Not authorized to edit this link" if @link.nil?
    end

    # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
    def link_params
      params.require(:link).permit(:title, :url)
    end
end
```

Besides double checking the source code, I've dropped the database and recreated it to see if I messed up the migration related to the gem and bounced the server. What am I missing here?